# Need help in determining the volume of styrofoam used with dimensions $2.50ft + 1.50ft + 1.00ft$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So to elaborate on the title, the question is this:

The average density of Styrofoam is $1.00 \frac{kg}{m^3}$.  If a Styrofoam cooler is made with outside dimensions of $3.00ft$ $x$ $2.00ft$ $x$ $1.50ft$ and inside dimensions of $2.50ft$ $x$ $1.50ft$ $x$ $1.00ft$, determine the (a) volume of Styrofoam used in the cubic meters...

So the word that is throwing me off is `used`.  Am I to calculate the volume of the inside and outside and simply add them?

I was doing the following:

$$V=lwh$$
$$V=(3.00)(2.00)(1.50)$$
(Outer)$V=9ft^3$
$$V=(2.50)(1.50)(1.00)$$
(Inner)$V=3.75ft^3$

(Total)$V=12.75ft^3$

Am I on the right track at all?

Comment: It is the **difference** that you want.  That gives you the combined volume of walls and top, i.e. the stuff made of styrofoam.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so would it simply be the inner volume, then?

Comment: You want the "outer" volume **minus** the inner volume.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks!  I guess I'm just having a hard time visualizing why taking the difference gives me a different volume than just calculating the inner volume?  I understand the math works, but I just can't see it in my mind yet.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think I got it. The question wants all the used volume including that being taken up by the depth of the Styrofoam?

Comment: The inner volume gives you the space in which you can store beer. The difference between outer volume and inner volume gives you the volume of the material the thing is made of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer volume gives you the amount of Styrofoam that it would take to make a cooler of the same size that was completely useless (because there was no space inside, as it was just a block of Styrofoam). The inner volume is the amount of Styrofoam that would have to be removed from such a block to make such a cooler. The amount of Styrofoam used, then, is the original/outer/useless volume minus the inner/removed volume. That is, the amount used is $5.25$ cubic feet.